# c++ <vector> Действия с значениями элементов вектора

Tags: c++, vector, stl

Доброго всем времени суток.

**Мне нужна помощь, чтобы дописать код этого задания:**

Разработать приложение для работы с данными, **которые хранятся в контейнере-векторе и вводятся
пользователем до тех пор, пока не будет выполнено условие прекращения ввода.**  Каждый элемент
вектор является набором данных, содержащий фамилию студента и оценки по 3-м предметам «Программирование»,
«Инженерная графика», «Компьютерная логика», **которые задаются пользователем.**

**Необходимо** по определенному **правилу R** в зависимости от содержимого набора вычислить определенный
результат, а также скопировать в новый вектор данные, выбранные из стартового по правилу **запроса Q.**

**Отобразить** содержимое стартового вектора (набор данных каждого элемента в новой строке из
указанием номера в массиве), результат вычислений с указанием правила и содержание результирующего
вектора (набор данных каждого элемента в новой строке с указанием номера в массиве) из
указанием соответствующего правила запроса.

**Правило R:** вычислить количество студентов, имеющих одинаковые оценки по любым двум
предметов

**Правило Q:** выбрать студентов, худшая оценка которых из трех предметов не менее 7

**Вот набросок кода:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
struct base
{
    char surname[25]; // поле-фамилия
    int mark1, mark2, mark3; // поле-оценка
};
int main()
{
    base item; // переменнная для сохранения элемента
    vector<base> vect; // создание пустого вектора элементов
    int count=0; // счётчик введённых элементов
    char ch; // символ для ответа на вопрос продолжения
    while(true) // бесконечный цикл
    {
        cout<<"Do you want to input a data of student? (y/n)"; // вопрос о продолжении ввода
        cin>>ch; // ввод ответа
        if(ch!='y'&&ch!='Y') // если ответ "нет"
            break; // прекращение цикла ввода
        count++; // увеличение счётчика элементов
        cout<<count<<endl; // вывод номера текущего элемента
        cout<<"Input surname:"; // запрос ввода фамилии
        cin>>item.surname;  // ввод фамилии
        cout<<"Input mark of Programming:"; // запрос ввода оценки по программированию
        cin>>item.mark1;// ввод оценки
        cout<<"Input mark of Computer Logic:"; // запрос ввода оценки по компъютерной логике
        cin>>item.mark2;// ввод оценки
        cout<<"Input mark of Engineer Graphic:";// запрос ввода оценки по инженерной графике
        cin>>item.mark3; // ввод оценки
        vect.push_back(item); // добавление в вектор этих элементов
    }
    cout<<"start:"<<endl;
    int bally=0;//счётчик рассчёта колличества одинаковых оценок
    for (int i=0; i < vect.size(); i++) // перебор всех элементов с привязкой к фактическому размеру

        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#include <iostream> // ввод-вывод
#include <vector> // вектор
#include <string> // строки
using namespace std;

bool low_seven(const int& f_mark, const int& s_mark, const int& t_mark) {
    if (f_mark >= 7 && s_mark >=7 && t_mark >= 7) { // сравниваем оценки. Если самая худшая должна быть больше или равна 7, значит все оценки больше или равны 7.
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
   }
}

bool compare_marks(const int& f_mark, const int& s_mark, const int& t_mark) {
// функция сравнения оценок. Если среди них есть две одинаковые, возвращает true
    if (f_mark==s_mark || f_mark==t_mark || s_mark==tmark) { // если две оценки одинаковые
        return true;
    } else { // иначе
        return false;
    }
}

struct student {
    string surname; // строка с фамилией
    int mark1, mark2, mark3; // оценки
}

int main() {
    unsigned int studsame = 0; // студенты с двумя одинаковыми оценками
    vector<student> studlist; // список студентов
    student Student; // элемент-структура
    unsigned int count = 0; // количество элементов
    char ch; // символ ответа на вопрос
    while (true) {
        cout << "Do you want write info about student? ";
        cin >> ch;
        if (ch=='y' || ch=='Y') { // если ответ положительный
           count++; // увеличиваем счетчик
           cout << count << endl; // вывод номера текущего элемента
           cout << "Write surname: "; // запрос на ввод фамилии
           cin >> Student.surname;
           cout << "Input mark of Programming: "; // запрос на оценку по программированию
           cin >> Student.mark1; // ввод оценки по программированию
           cout << "Input mark of Computer Logic: "; // запрос на оценку по компьютерной логике
           cin >> Student.mark2; // ввод оценки по компьютерной логике
           cout << "Input mark of Engineer graphic: "; // запрос на ввод оценки по компьютерной графике
           cin >> Student.mark3; // ввод оценки по компьютерной графике
           studlist.push_back(Student); // добавляем студента в список
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int i=0; i<studlist.size(); i++) { // цикл для подсчета по условию R
        bool issame; // переменная для определения, одинаковы ли оценки
        issame = compare_marks(studlist.at(i).mark1, studlist.at(i).mark2, studlist.at(i).mark3); // сравниваем оценки
        if (issame) {
            studsame++;
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int jk=0; jk<studlist.size(); jk++) { // Цикл для подсчета по условию Q
        bool notsmall; // переменная для определения, низкая ли оценка
        notsmall = low_seven(studlist.at(jk).mark1, studlist.at(jk).mark2, studlist.at(jk).mark3); // определяем, низкая ли оценка
        if (notsmall) {
            string goodstudent = studlist.at(jk).surname; // фамилия студента с хорошими оценками. Что с ней делать: вывести на экран, или что-то ещё, вы не указывали.
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Да. Мне нужно вывести на экран фамилию, ибо выводится логическое значение.

Comment: ну тогда ```cout << studlist.at(jk).surname << endl;```